# Premiere Pro ducks audio when nobody asked it to

Tags: adobe, premiere

I'm experiencing this weird thing with Premiere Pro. I have a track with background music, and a track with sound effects. If the sound effect track volume is higher than the volume of the background music track, the volume of the background music will go even quieter, and it will stay so even after the sound effects are done playing. The actual volume doesn't change, but it sounds quieter. The higher the volume of the sound effects track, the quieter the background music will go - even to the point of being barely audible. I repeat that this problem persists even after the sound effects are done playing and there's only music going on. This happened across multiple projects and with different music and sound effects, both in Premiere and After Effects.

As I just discovered, that's called audio ducking. However, as far as I understand, if you want it, you need to tell Premiere to do it by selecting the music you want to duck and specify what to duck against. I did no such thing, and in fact, I made sure that no ducking is enabled at all. Yet, it happens. Is it a bug? Is there some other option I am unaware of? Could it be something else entirely?